# Can sampling an input texture in shader return values updated in same pass?

Tags: directx, hlsl, fragment-shader

In my hlsl, (I am using Direct2D helpers which I guess just call tex2D), can `D2DSampleInputAtOffset()` return a pixel value that was only updated in that same pass of the shader? Or will it always return the value the sample had before the shader has processed any pixel? e.g.:

```
#define D2D_INPUT_COUNT 1
#define D2D_INPUT0_COMPLEX
#include "d2d1effecthelpers.hlsli"

D2D_PS_ENTRY(main)
{
    float4 color = D2DGetInput(0);


    float4 above = D2DSampleInputAtOffset(0, float2(0, -1));
    // will above be the value in the sample before drawing with this shader?
}
```

Further is there a specific sequence in which pixels are processed by my shader, e.g. left to right, top to bottom?